# Почему в mysql на дату ставят длину значения 11 вместо 10?

Tags: mysql

Начал оптимизацию бд, посчитал, что в функции time 10 цифр. Когда будет 11, то наступит 2400 год.

Вопрос: почему люди пишут int(11) вместо int(10)?

Comment: Для int`a 11 - это не длина значения, а длина для вывода. Правда вывод будет замечен, только если укажите zerofill.

[Здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552223/int11-vs-intanything-else) расписано подробнее (с примерами).

Comment: И, кстати, когда по дефолту используется 10, а когда 11, можно посмотреть [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256560/mysql-datatype-int11-whereas-unsigned-int10)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для int`а значение в скобках указывает не на длину значения, не на размер значения, а показывает лишь возможную длину вывода. И только в случае, когда у столбца указан атрибут `zerofill`

Рассмотрим примеры:

```
>> CREATE TABLE test (
    id INT,
    id1 INT(10),
    id2 INT(11),
    id3 INT(2),
    id4 INT(10) ZEROFILL,
    id5 INT(11) ZEROFILL,
    id6 INT(2) ZEROFILL
);

>> SHOW CREATE TABLE test;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id1` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id3` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id4` int(10) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
  `id5` int(11) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
  `id6` int(2) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

>> INSERT INTO test VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
    (111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111);

>> SELECT * FROM test;
+------+------+------+------+------------+-------------+------+
| id   | id1  | id2  | id3  | id4        | id5         | id6  |
+------+------+------+------+------------+-------------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 | 0000000001 | 00000000001 |   01 |
|  111 |  111 |  111 |  111 | 0000000111 | 00000000111 |  111 |
+------+------+------+------+------------+-------------+------+
```

Для столбцов `id`, `id1`, `id2`, `id3` мы не указали атрибут `ZEROFILL` и в выводе этих столбцов нет никаких различий даже несмотря на то, что размер вывода для этих столбцов отличается.

Для столбцов `id4`, `id5`, `id6` мы указали атрибут `ZEROFILL` и для каждого столбца свой размер вывода, поэтому если длина строкового представления числа меньше размера вывода (размера, указанного в скобках), то строковое представление числа будет дополнено нулями слева до требуемой длины.

Если же длина строкового представления числа больше размера вывода (столбец `id6` и его значение `111`), то никакого дополнения нулями не происходит

---

Стоит обратить внимание на поле `id` - размер вывода для него мы не указывали, но при этом в `SHOW CREATE TABLE` размер все равно проставлен и равен `11`.

`11` - т.к. столбец `id` у нас `INT`, т.е. целое знаковое, согласно [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html) там может быть значение равное `-2147483648`, что как раз равно 11 знакам (10 цифр + знак минус)

Если же мы опишем столбец как `INT UNSIGNED`, то отрицательных значений быть не может (знака минус), а максимальное по длине число равно `4294967295`, что равняется 10 знакам. Поэтому для `INT UNSIGNED` в выводе `SHOW CREATE TABLE` будет указано `INT(10)`

Comment: бомба, где вы такую информацию изучаете?