# как посмотреть данные в таблице через консоль SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Как посмотреть данные в таблице через консоль SQL?

Comment: по второму вашему вопросу можете почитать мой [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/443738/5079)

Comment: автор, Вас интересуют именно MySQL базы?

Answer (score 2):

Посмотреть данные в таблице можно через выполнение запроса `SELECT * FROM tableName;`

Comment: а по другому?  Например, вот так мы смотрим все таблицы в БД - show tables;

Comment: Чем вас не устраивает SELECT * FROM tableName?

Comment: Я хочу узнать для чего нужно использовать - int(вот тут размер, по умолчанию он равен 11) . Предполагается что если установить 1 то боле одного числа в консоль не выведется.

Comment: @semiromid `int` - integer(то есть цифры), `11` - количество цифр

Answer (score 0):

У консольных клиентов бывают специальные команды, отображающие информацию о таблице. Например, в `psql` есть `\d+ name_table`, которая показывает поля записи и комментарии к ним.